# Proof that vectors span a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a matrix of $m \times n$ dimensions and $B$ be a matrix of $n \times m$ dimensions such that $AB=I_{m}$. If $v_{1},...,v_{k}$ are vectors spanning $\mathbb{R^{n}}$, prove that $Av_{1},...,Av_{k}$ span $\mathbb{R^{m}}$.

To approach this problem, is it okay to prove that $Av_{1},...,Av_{k}$ form a subspace of $\mathbb{R^{m}}$ and then to say: since $v_{1},...,v_{k}$ span $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ then it follows that $Av_{1},...,Av_{k}$ span $\mathbb{R^{m}}$?

Comment: Check the statement you want to prove carefylly. As written it is not true (if A is a zero matrix or a matrix of 'unsuitable' rank).

Comment: I don't see how it can be true. ·$Av_k$ elements are not even vectors, but $m\times n$ matrices. They are not elements of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: The claim is false if $m>n$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the full statement to prove. Have edited now...?